# Add CSS file on delete specific node

Tags: theming, 7, modal-dialogs, nodes

How can I add a css file to the specific page where you delete a node of type = ... . I know you can add css files to specific pages like this:

```
function hook_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
    $path = current_path();

    if ($path == 'user/login') {
        drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'hook') . "/css/login.css", array('weight' => 1000));
    }
}
```

But when I want to delete a node as a user the delete modal opens in overlay. And when I then check the path he just gives me the path of the underlaying page of the overay.

This is how the overlay of deleting a node looks now:
[image]

But I want to add a css file to the specific overlay, how can I do this?

Comment: So you want to apply alternate style for first page shown after node deletion? Or what, exactly? Sorry, but I can't quite imagine what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to use css on the page of node deletion, see the screenshot in my topic.

Comment: And why can't you use `<body>` classes `.page-node-delete` and `.node-type-typename` in your main CSS file to get this effect?

Comment: Just to clarify, it wasn't a rhetoric question, I genuinely want to understand your use case. Without that understanding it might be hard to provide answer that's really useful.